# CSS or Coding? How to make results listed side by side instead of ontop of eachother

Tags: html, css

Hello I run a music website and it is in beta at the moment. I have a problem, the music results when loaded into a bottom player lists songs ontop of one another. I want them to be listed side by side but am having trouble doing so.  How would you go about formatting a list of results as they are one ontop of eachother to list each search results side by side?

For example Song ''result 1'' "result 2'' "result 3"

instead of result 1
           result 2
           result 3

```
#current_playlist_rows {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 360px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 3px solid transparent;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 500000px;
}
```

this makes the playlist flat and how i want it. but how do i make this scrollable to the right or left??

Comment: What is the player & what is your existing code?

Answer (score 2):

Say it's a `li`, with the class `results`, then you do the following:

```
li.results ul{
  list-style: none;
}

li.results {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: okay so this worked pretty well, the css looks good on it however now my problem is that it doesnt move the search results when i click skip.

Comment: So, please tell me how on earth we are supposed to help you if we don't have access to your code? How should we know what "skip" is? You really need to isolate the problem, and post some code, if you want more help. I don't mean to be harsh, but we can't guess what your code looks like...

Comment: Is there anyway we could chat on skype or email? I would feel more comfortable posting code there

Comment: This is a public Q&A site, not a personal support site. If you can't generalize the code so that everyone can benefit from the questions and answers, I'm sorry. If you want to pay me to help you in person, of course, that's another question, but, StackOverflow is not for personal help. It's for sharing with the public :)

Comment: Paying is an option too, but i just posted the code if you want to check out how to make it scrollable to the left or right to filter through the search results

Comment: `overflow:scroll` instead of `overflow:auto` should do the trick.

Comment: Hey that worked great :) thanks mate. i mean its not perfect and has a few measurement problems but its a start.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the results in a div tags and give them style -> float:left and some width, andd it will display them side by side :)

Example:

```
 <div style='width:500px; float:left;height:100px;'></div>
 <div style='width:370px; float:left;height:350px;'></div>
```

I hope that helped :)

Comment: thanks man I will try it out, is there anyway i could private message if i get stuck again? I could show some of the code.

Comment: It's a list of song, you should use `ul` and `li` instead of `div`

Comment: there is no problem of using just the div code, the ul's are just for good look ;)